# How to unshift to append under spicific div in Vue

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

I have comments and this comment containe likes, My propblem is when I try to push replay to the comment it is append to the wrong comment, So I used `this.$el;` to get the target comment bu the propblem is `unshift/push` just use with list and it shows error `push is not a function`

My qustion is how I can use `unshift/push` to append under spicific div not list

```
    async addReplay(comment, e){
              const element = this.$el; //this to get the target div
}
```

here the post replay function

```
      async getaddReplay(id, setReplayPlace){
        

                await axios.get('/account/api/auth/user/')
                        .then(response => {
                            this.currentUserImage = response.data.profile_image
                        })

                const replayData = {
                     content: this.commentReplayContent,
                     video: this.$route.params.video_id,
                     parent: id
                }
                await axios.post(`/video/api/video/comment/${id}/replay/create/`, replayData)



               .then(response => {
                    console.log(this.setReplayPlace)
// here I want append the item to spicific div
                    this.setReplayPlace.unshift({ content: this.commentReplayContent,  author:  this.$store.state.user.username, id:response.data.id, author_image:this.currentUserImage, video:this.$route.params.video_id  ,likes:0, total_parents:0, check_like: false, publish:'now'})
                    this.commentReplayContent = ''
               })

               .catch(error => {
                   console.log(error)
               })
        }
```

**Edit**

Here there are comments with replies component and I pass the data to repliy component using props

```
     <ul  v-for="(comment, index)  in comments"  :key="index">
          <li class="comment-object">
            <div class="image-container">
              <img class="profile-pic" :src="comment.author_image" v-on:change="currentUserImage" alt="profile picture" id="user_video_comment_profile_image" refs="user_video_comment_profile_image" />
            </div>
            <div class="comment-text">
              <h2 class="username" style="color: #C2C3C4">{{comment.author}} <span class="muted">&#183; {{comment.publish}}</span>
              <DeleteComment :comment="comment" v-if="comments || index" :comments="comments" :index="index"  />
              </h2>
              <p class="comment">{{comment.content}} </p>
                              
           <RepliesJustAdded @justAddedReplies="addRepliesToParent" :replaiesJustAdded="replaiesJustAdded" :setReplayPlace="setReplayPlace" :allReplies="allReplies" :replaiesData="replaiesData" v-if="replaiesJustAdded || setReplayPlace || allReplies || replaiesData" />
            </div>
          </li>
        </ul>
```

The Replay component

```
     <ul  v-for="replay  in replies"  :key="replay.id"  id="video_comments_replies" > 
                                            <li class="comment-object">
                                                <div class="image-container">
                                                <img class="profile-pic" :src="replay.author_image" alt="profile picture" id="user_video_comment_profile_image" refs="user_video_comment_profile_image" />
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="comment-text">
                                                <h2 class="username" style="color: #C2C3C4">{{replay.author}} <span class="muted">&#183; {{replay.publish}}</span></h2>
                                                <p class="comment">{{replay.content}} </p>
                                                
                                                 <RepliesActionButtons :replay="replay" />

                                                </div>
                                            </li>
                                     </ul>
```

Comment: Could you provide the code of the component? It is not clear how you render your data.

Comment: Did you mean the template?

Comment: Yes. The more code you provide, the more will be clear to solve your problem.

Comment: I updated my qustion

Answer (score 1):

I didn't find the line where you are trying to call `push` but I thing I know what's wrong: your are trying to call `push` but array-like collections don't have such method. You should convert your collection to array before calling `push`. Try something like that:

```
// create a `NodeList` object
const divs = document.querySelectorAll('div');

// convert `NodeList` to an array
const divsArr = Array.from(divs);
```

After that all methods of `Array.prototype` will be available.